# emacs: Finding a substring in a string using (string-match)

Tags: regex, emacs

Why does the code produce the same result?

```
(setq line "@c *##**@w{@ref{ФайлыКаталоги,, ФайлыКаталоги}}**##*")
(string-match "*##**" line) ;(eval-last-sexp) => 3
(string-match "**##*" line) ;(eval-last-sexp) => 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use asterisk shielding

```
(setq line "@c *##**@w{@ref{ФайлыКаталоги,, ФайлыКаталоги}}**##*")
(string-match "\\*##\\*\\*" line) ;(eval-last-sexp) => 3
(string-match "\\*\\*##\\*" line) ;(eval-last-sexp) => 47
```

and you can do as advised Drew

```
(setq line "@c *##**@w{@ref{ФайлыКаталоги,, ФайлыКаталоги}}**##*")
(string-match "*##\\*\\*" line) ;(eval-last-sexp) => 3
(string-match "*\\*##\\*" line) ;(eval-last-sexp) => 47
```

Comment: Use [`regexp-quote`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Functions.html) to easily quote all regular expression special characters: `(string-match (regexp-quote "*##**") line)`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what you found, note that the first asterisk (`*`) in each of your regexps is **not** a special regexp char.  So you need not escape it, to match an asterisk literally. The Elisp manual, node [Regexp Special](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html), says this:

> *Please note:* For historical compatibility, special characters are
>   treated as ordinary ones if they are in contexts where their special
>   meanings make no sense.
>
> For example, `*foo` treats `*` as ordinary
>   since there is no preceding expression on which the `*` can act.  It is
>   poor practice to depend on this behavior; quote the special character
>   anyway, regardless of where it appears.

So yes, it's fine to escape it, but be aware that that first `*` would never act specially, even if you didn't escape it. To act specially, `*` has to follow something.

Comment: here, the search is not based on a regular expression mapping, but on a string mapping. I don't understand, what are the regular expressions here?

Comment: `C-h f string-match` tells you that the search pattern is matched as a *regexp*: `Return index of start of first match for REGEXP in STRING, or nil.`

Comment: I didn't provide a regular expression here, but a term. Therefore, I did not follow the special characters for the regular expression.

Comment: Yes, you did provide a regexp, as the first arg to `string-match`. "Term" means nothing (to me) here. The string first-args you passed, `"*##**"` and `"**##*"`, *are regexps*. The string `"dog"` is a regexp. And the point here is that *whatever* string you pass to `string-match` is interpreted by it as a regexp - even strings that are invalid as regexps. It is `string-match` that determines, by its behavior, that the arg is treated as a regexp.